# What does DNA taste like?

Tags: dna, taste, gustation

I've seen plenty of speculation online, but does anyone know of a scientific study or have a definitive argument?

I'm thinking probably not sweet, because the deoxyribose sugar is bound in the structure of the helix. Salty, due to group I counterions? Bitter due to the alkaline phosphate groups? I'm guessing not sour, because despite the name nucleic acids are in their conjugate base form at physiological pH. I've read some nucleotides can activate the umami/savory taste, would this be significant?

I am aware essentially everything we eat contains DNA, but I'm interested in the taste of DNA itself, pure/isolated if necessary you like.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology in the terms of this list.

Comment: Where can the list be found so I can review? I feel it is a question about a biological sensation of a significant biomolecule. Is there a SE site that is more applicable?

Comment: This is a valid question. It asks for objectively verifiable answers. Tastes are not subjective. Nobody in the entire universe tasets glucose to be bitter. Even if we have deseases that cause deviations in taste, we still can resort to statistics. Most of people would taste the same, because that's statistical mode.

Answer (score 2):

Youtube chemist NileRed chemically extracted DNA from strawberries in this video, he also tastes it if I remember correctly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=araeHtN_3Lk

TL;DW: He gets the DNA from the strawberries and says it has a slimy texture as it isn't soluble, and it tastes salty more than anything. Note though that this could be from leftover reactants from the reaction, so take this with a grain of salt.